# PHP variable into JavaScript url

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I have been trying to figure this out. The image path and href are php variables.

```
echo'<a href="'. $bigImg[0]->src .'"><img src="'. $thumbImg[0]->src .'" alt="" /></a>';
echo'<a href="'. $bigImg[1]->src .'"><img src="'. $thumbImg[1]->src .'" alt="" /></a>';
```

I am trying to turn the php variables into a javascript.

The PHP variables are:

```
'. $bigImg[0]->src .'
'. $thumbImg[0]->src .'
```

How can I pass this into javascript?

Comment: That makes no sense. Turn PHP vars into `a javascript`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use them in JavaScript? Also, [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: please elaborate your question!

Comment: yes how can I make those image paths into javascript?

Comment: That still makes no sense.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but if I guess, I would say that you should use JQuery or some library that is easy to learn, so you select all the images, then grab all the href properties of that array and use it for whatever you want. Plain JS will be more difficult, I think.

Comment: you want to translate this code into javascript?

Comment: yes, yes yes how can you translate it into javacript. Do I make a php variable into a javascript variable?

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if your page is generated by PHP

you would start off with

This is all inside a PHP file, lets call it index.php

```
<?php
// These are your arrays which contain your objects that can call their src public member.
$bigImg = array();
$thumbBig = array(); 

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var bigImgSrc = <?php echo json_encode($bigImg[0]->src); ?>;
            var thumbBigSrc = <?php echo json_encode($thumbImg[0]=>src); ?>;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood correctly.. i would do something like:

```
<script>
var bigSrc='<?=$bigImg[0]-src;?>';
var thumbSrc='<?=thumbImg[0]->src;?>';
</script>
```

then, in the appropriate place

```
document.write("<a href="'+bigSrc+"'><img....</a>")
```

or via Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("<a href="'+bigSrc+"'><img....</a>").appendTo(parentnode..)
})
</script>
```

Comment: Not properly esacped, your quotes are imbalanced, and you’re missing a `>`. `document.write` is a bad idea.

Comment: so whats in between img ...

Comment: @minitech: why should document.write be a bad idea? I've proposed two different approach it's up to the OP to chose the one hat best fits its needings.

jaz, sorry for the  unbalanced quotes; as you may have seen it should be 
$("<a href='"+bigSrc+"'><img src='"+thumbSrc+"'>....</a>").appendTo(parentnode..)